# Discord.js Cannot read property 'send' of undefined and some other small problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I use https://github.com/UnrealSecurity/jdclient as the command handler now.
I have tried for hours to make this working but it just doesn't work. The only error im getting now is
"Cannot read property 'send' of undefined" but i feel like it will have other errors after its fixed
The code should send a copy of message, deleted message, edited message to a channel. It worked some while ago but now its broken -.- 
I'm having problems with this code:

```
// import library
const { JDClient, Discord } = require('./src/');
const { prefix, token, logsChannel } = require('./config.json');
client = new Discord.Client();
// define minimum bot options
const options = {
  token: 'TOKEN',
  trigger: '?'
};


// build bot commands
const commands = {
  help: {
    run: (message, pars, arr)=>{
      message.reply('**Available commands:** \n' + Object.keys(bot.commands).join(', '))
    }
  }
};


// create bot instance
var bot = new JDClient(options, commands);

// Messages log
bot.discord.on('message', message => {
  // Function
  function isEmpty(collection) {
      for(var arg in collection) {
          if(collection.hasOwnProperty(arg))
              return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
  // Logs
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  let username = message.author.tag;
  let channel = message.channel.name;
  let server = message.channel.guild;
var serverAvatarURL = message.guild.iconURL;
  var attachment = (message.attachments).array();
  if(isEmpty(attachment)) {
      var img = "";
  } else {
      var img = attachment[0].url;
  }

  let embed_send = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(username, message.author.avatarURL)
      .setColor('23c115')
      .setTitle("Message sent!")
      .setDescription(message.content + " " + img)
      .setImage(img)
      .setFooter("#" + channel)
      .setTimestamp();
      client.channels.cache.get(logsChannel).send(embed_send);
});

// Message edit log
bot.discord.on("messageUpdate", async(oldMessage, newMessage) => {
  // Function
  function isEmpty(collection) {
      for(var arg in collection) {
          if(collection.hasOwnProperty(arg))
              return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
  // Logs
  if (oldMessage.content === newMessage.content) {
      return;
  }

  var attachment = (oldMessage.attachments).array();
  if(isEmpty(attachment)) {
      var img = "";
  } else {
      var img = attachment[0].url;
  }

  let embed_edit = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(oldMessage.author.tag, oldMessage.author.avatarURL)
      .setColor('2615c1')
  .setTitle("Message edited!")
      .addField("Old", oldMessage.content + " " + img, true)
  .addField("New", newMessage.content + " " + img, true)
      .setFooter("#" + oldMessage.channel.name)
      .setTimestamp();
  client.channels.cache.get(logsChannel).send(embed_edit);
});

// Message delete log
bot.discord.on("messageDelete", async message => {
  // Function
  function isEmpty(collection) {
      for(var arg in collection) {
          if(collection.hasOwnProperty(arg))
              return false;
      }
      return true;
  }
  // Logs
  var attachment = (message.attachments).array();
  if(isEmpty(attachment)) {
      var img = "";
  } else {
      var img = attachment[0].url;
  }

  let embed_delete = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL)
  .setColor('c11515')
  .setTitle("Message deleted!")
  .setDescription(message.content + " " + img)
  .setImage(img)
  .setFooter("#" + message.channel.name)
  .setTimestamp();    
  client.channels.cache.get(logsChannel).send(embed_delete);
}),

      bot.discord.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(0x00d0ff)
      .setTitle("New user joined!")
      .setDescription("Welcome, " + member + "!")
      .setFooter("https://discord.gg/xHusQ4d", "https://cdn.drawception.com/images/panels/2017/10-13/P7sMKBC2pR-4.png")
      .setTimestamp()
      client.channels.cache.get(member.guild.systemChannelID).send({embed});
          },
      )
      bot.discord.on("guildMemberRemove", (member) => {
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor(0x00d0ff)
      .setTitle("Bye!")
      .setDescription("Good bye, " + member + "!")
      .setFooter("https://discord.gg/xHusQ4d", "https://cdn.drawception.com/images/panels/2017/10-13/P7sMKBC2pR-4.png")
      .setTimestamp()
      bot.discord.channels.get(member.guild.systemChannelID).send({embed});
      }),

      bot.discord.onConnect = ()=>{
          console.log('We are logged into Dickcord!');
       }


bot.commands = {

  botstatus: {
    text: 'Changes bot status',
    run: (args, pars, arr) => {
        bot.discord.user.setActivity(arr.join(' '), { type: "WATCHING" });
        args.delete(1)
        console.log(args.author.tag, 'used the botstatus command!');
        },  
    },

     joke: {
        text: "fun",
        run: (args, pars, arr) => {
            var facts = ["Yo mama's so fat, when she skips a meal, the stock market drops ", "Yo mama's so fat, when she fell I didn't laugh, but the sidewalk cracked up.", "Yo mama's so fat, it took me two buses and a train to get to her good side.", "Why do cows never have any money? Because the farmers milk them dry!", "My wife told me I had to stop acting like a flamingo. So I had to put my foot down.", "As I suspected, someone has been adding soil to my garden. The plot thickens.", "When a deaf person sees someone yawn do they think it’s a scream?", "What did the traffic light say to the car? Don’t look! I’m about to change.", "Somebody stole my microsoft office and they're going to pay - you have my Word.", "What did the left eye say to the right eye? Between you and me, something smells."];
            var fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);
            args.channel.send("Finding fun jokes... "),
            args.channel.send(facts[fact]);
            args.delete(1)
            console.log(args.author.tag, 'used the joke command!');

        },
     },

    facts: {
        text: "facts",
        run: (args, pars, arr) => {
            var facts = ["Hawaiian pizza was invented by a Greek man in Canada. ", "The world’s first cosmonaut was a dog.", "Ketchup was invented in China.", "All blue-eyed people have a common ancestor.", "Workers are most productive on Mondays.", "The human eye can detect the light of a candle from over a mile away.", "You can tell if someone really likes you by looking at their feet while you talk.", "The oldest “your mom” joke dates from ancient Babylonia", "Penguin urine makes up about 3% of Antarctica’s glaciers.", "The name for the fear of long words is 36 letters long. ", "Nutella was originally invented as a way to stretch chocolate rations.", "A cat named Sweet Tart is the Mayor of Omena, Michigan.", "There is a medical procedure to remove the sense of fear.", "Genghis Khan has about 16 million living descendants.", "Grapes are toxic to dogs.", "Barbie’s full name is Barbara Millicent Roberts.", "Some snakes can sense when an earthquake is coming.", "Killer whales aren’t really whales.", "90% of the world’s fresh water is in Antarctica.",];
            var fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);
            args.channel.send("searching for facts... "),
            args.channel.send(facts[fact]);
            args.delete(1)
            console.log(args.author.tag, 'used the facts command!');
        },
        command: {
            text: "command name",
            run: (args, pars, arr) => {
                args.channel.send("command")
            }
        }
    },
    roulette: {
    text: "russian roulette",
    run: (args, pars, arr) => {
        var facts = ["YOU LOSE!", "YOU WIN!", "YOU LOSE!", "YOU WIN!", "YOU LOSE!", "YOU WIN!",];
        var fact = Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length);

        args.react('').then(() => args.react('❤'));
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return ['', '❤'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === args.author.id;
        };
        args.channel.send("Pick a color! Black or red!")
        args.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
        args.channel.send(facts[fact]);
        } else {
        args.channel.send(facts[fact]);
        }
        })
        .catch(collected => {
        args.channel.send('you reacted with neither a black, nor a red.');
        });
        }
    },
}
// bind bot events, all of these are optional
bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('We are logged into Discord!');
});

bot.on('message', (event) => {
  let { client, text, data } = event;
  console.log(text);
});

bot.on('error', (event) => {
  const { client, text, data } = event;
  console.log(text);
});

bot.on('debug', (event) => {
  const { client, text, data } = event;
  console.log(text);
});
```

full error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CryT0r\Desktop\botty\app.js:56:45)
    at Client.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\CryT0r\Desktop\botty\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\CryT0r\Desktop\botty\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\CryT0r\Desktop\botty\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)  
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\CryT0r\Desktop\botty\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:435:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\CryT0r\Desktop\botty\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\CryT0r\Desktop\botty\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\CryT0r\Desktop\botty\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:801:20)
```

Comment: Can you please include the full error, not just the error message (`"Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"`). Whats interesting is the line number. And if you can, please include ALL relevant code, and remove any irrelevant code.

Comment: Ah yeah i have now added the full error at the bottom of the post. And im using JDclient (https://github.com/UnrealSecurity/jdclient) as the command handler. I will put the whole code to that now.

Comment: Cannot read property 'B' of undefined means there's `A.B` somewhere in your code and `A` is undefined, that's it. Use console.log() and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing is pointing to this line in your app.js:

```
client.channels.cache.get(logsChannel).send(embed_send);
```

It is telling you that `client.channels.cache.get(logsChannel)` is retuning `undefined`, so some places you can start debugging include adding a `console.log(client.channels.cache)` right before line 56 to see if the cache is, in fact, holding what you are expecting it to hold. You might also want to look at your config.json file where you are storing the `logsChannel` value to see if it still matches the value you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try that

Comment: The answer i got from console.log was ´´´Collection [Map] { ``` and after that it just gave the same error

Comment: This map represents all of the cached channels that `client.channels` is keeping track of, is this collection empty? If so then you might want to look at the `jdclient` library for any documentation about errors that it might have returned earlier.  If this collection is not empty then you should look at the value you have stored in `config.json` to see if it matches any of values in the map, you may be holding on to an expected value that actually changes over time.

Comment: So has this question been solved at all? Cause I'm wondering there's nothing new to this issue.